# Not able to run hibernate query because of Syntax exception

Tags: java, hibernate

Query is working properly with MySQL. Can anybody help me to correct the syntax in hibernate?

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("DELETE FROM HierarchyData WHERE id IN (SELECT c.id FROM (SELECT h.id FROM HierarchyData AS h WHERE h.publicId IN (SELECT s.publicId FROM HierarchyData AS s GROUP BY s.publicId HAVING COUNT(s.publicId)>1) AND h.id NOT IN (SELECT m.id FROM HierarchyData AS m GROUP BY m.publicId HAVING COUNT(m.publicId)>1 ORDER BY m.id DESC) ORDER BY h.publicId) AS c)");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`EntityManager.createNativeQuery(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery-java.lang.String-) to create a query from an `SQL` string.

`createQuery(String)` instead would have to be used with a [`JPQL`](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E13946_04/ejb3_langref.html) string.

Comment: Thank u Florian Cramer. It is working properly.